# Why is Git tracking file permissions?

Tags: git, macos, github

I downloaded a backup of a web app (as a tar.gz file containing HTML, PHP, JS, and CSS files) from a VPS to update the files I have in a Git repository.
I immediately noticed that Git marked most of the files as modified, even though they didn't change. This holds for all file types - text files, and even images.
I went ahead and pushed the changes to the remote repository (GitHub) and found that Git tracked the change in file permissions.
The Git repo was created on Windows originally and updating the files in it was done similarly to the way described above. What causes Git to track file permissions and how can I avoid this from happening?

Environment:
git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
OS: MacOS 14.2.1

I attach a demo image of the GitHub web UI below:

[image: Demo image of a permission change tracked by Git]

**Edit:** It turned out that the file permissions for some files were changed on the server for some reason and these changed permissions were carried over with the archive file. How can I make the files have their previously committed permissions (restore the permissions to how they were before) using Git?
Are there any negative consequences of turning off `fileMode` in Git? I did a quick online search and found some people recommended not to turn it off.

Comment: Git doesn't track file permissions in general, but it does track "readable" vs "executable" so that you you can run scripts/binaries/etc in the repository.

Comment: This is like someone on Linux asking “Why does Git track file extensions?” It simply matters on some platforms, although not on all.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your IDE is errantly setting things as executable.

The file executable bit absolutely is useful information and absolutely does have an effect in Mac OSX and Linux.

In general, unless your text file has a bangline (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`) at the top of the file, you don't want to have the executable bit set.

If you cannot tame your editor's tendency to set files as executable, you can tell Git to ignore changes to file permissions using this command:

```bash
git config --global core.fileMode false
```

(If you so choose, you can also do this on a repo-by-repo basis by leaving out the `--global` when you execute that command after `cd`-ing into a repo's working directory)

Git only tracks whether the "owner" executable bit is set (`chmod u+x`). It doesn't track any of the read/write bits or the "group" or "world" executable bits, even though `diff` will show modes 0644/0755.

Comment: I found out the file permissions were changed for some reason on some of the original files hosted on the Linux server. The files with original permissions "775" turned into "755" in Git and those with original permissions "664" turned into "644" in Git. (On my local machine containing the repository, the files with 664 permissions are -rwxrwxrwx. I guess git doesn't store write permissions for "group" and "other"?)
I've done a quick online research and I see some people do not recommend disabling fileMode. I don't understand why. I just want to reset the permissions to 755 and 644 for now.

Comment: Git only tracks whether the "owner" executable bit is set (`chmod u+x`). It doesn't track any of the any read/write bits or the "group" or "world" executable bits, even though `diff` will show modes 0644/0755.